# Send Form data on base of selected User in angular5

Tags: angular, forms, typescript

I am using common reactive form for multiple types of user data .like some users have additional data like teacher,student,guard etc . Form is selected from drop down list

I want to send just specific data object according to selected user. I have create a Model named as "user" that contains all common and diff fields . now i want to send data as below

```
 selectedUser:string; //form selected like teacher etc   
 submit(data){
   if(selectedUser === 'Teacher'){
     let techobj =new User(data.name,data.address,data.degree);
        this.userservice.post(url,teachobj);
        }
   if(selectedUser === 'Student'){
     let stuobj =new User(data.name,data.address,data.semester);
       this.userservice.post(url,stuobj);  
      }
    ..... so on
}
```

Model class

```
export class User{
    //all fields here

     constructor(name :string,address:string,semester ?:string ,degree?:string)
}
```

**Problem**
        can't overload constructor or create object with diff params like Java or C#

Comment: Hi. What do you mean by overloading the constructor? Not everybody here has a background in langauges like `Java` or `C#`. Thanks

Comment: I think she wanted to do something like named parameters or something but usual approach is more like User's inherited class or just pass everytime all parameter and consider "null" for the undesirable one

Comment: @naila Check my answer for using interfaces, if you are looking for this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an interface with mandatory and optional propertes which you require to be passed in special cases like below

```
export interface IUser{
  name: string;
  address: string;
  semester?: string,
  degree?: string
}
```

Here name,address are mandatory for each case but semester and degree can be passed based on condition.

You can use this interface in the constructor of your `User` class like below to set the value of the properties.

```
export class User{
    //all fields here
  public name: string;
  public address: string;
  public semester?: string;
  public degree?: string;

  constructor(user:IUser) {
    this.name = user.name;
    this.address = user.address;
    this.semester = user.semester;
    this.degree = user.degree;
  }

}
```

Finally you can create the instance of the class like the below approach -

```
let data2:IUser = { name: data.name, address: data.address, degree: data.degree};
let techobj = new User(data2);
```

OR you can do it like this

```
let techobj2 = new User({ name: data.name, address: data.address, degree: data.degree});
```

Similarly for `Student` you can create the instance like this -

```
let techobj3 = new User({ name: data.name, address: data.address, semester:data.semester });
```

Here is the complete code -

```
export interface IUser{
  name: string;
  address: string;
  semester?: string,
  degree?: string
}

 export class User{
    //all fields here
  public name: string;
  public address: string;
  public semester?: string;
  public degree?: string;

  constructor(user:IUser) {
    this.name = user.name;
    this.address = user.address;
    this.semester = user.semester;
    this.degree = user.degree;
  }

}

let data:IUser = { name: "Niladri", address: "123", degree: "GRAD" };
let techobj = new User(data);

///OR 
let techobj2 = new User({ name: "Niladri", address: "123", degree: "GRAD" });

//Similary 

let techobj3 = new User({ name: "Niladri", address: "123", semester:"6th" });

console.log(techobj2.degree); //GRAD
console.log(techobj3.semester); //6th
```

And your service call should be like this -

```
selectedUser:string; //form selected like teacher etc   
 submit(data){
   if(selectedUser === 'Teacher'){
     let techobj =new User({ name: data.name, address: data.address, degree: data.degree});
        this.userservice.post(url,teachobj);
        }
   if(selectedUser === 'Student'){
     let stuobj =new User({ name: data.name, address: data.address, semester:data.semester });
       this.userservice.post(url,stuobj);  
      }
    ..... so on
}
```

P.S - if you pass null in your current constructor for the undesired params then it would also work

Edit 2: Another approach is to create a base class `User` and inherit from that class to create `Student` and `Teacher` class, then call `super()` in the constructor of the child classes to pass the `name,address` property value to the base `User` class.But there will be many child classes in this case depending on the number of if conditions

working demo :

[Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%20interface%20IUser%7B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20address%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20semester%3F%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20degree%3F%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20class%20User%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fall%20fields%20here%0D%0A%20%20public%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20address%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20semester%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20degree%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor(user%3AIUser)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20user.name%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.address%20%3D%20user.address%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.semester%20%3D%20user.semester%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.degree%20%3D%20user.degree%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20data%3AIUser%20%3D%20%7B%20name%3A%20%22Niladri%22%2C%20address%3A%20%22123%22%2C%20degree%3A%20%22GRAD%22%20%7D%3B%0D%0Alet%20techobj%20%3D%20new%20User(data)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%2FOR%20%0D%0Alet%20techobj2%20%3D%20new%20User(%7B%20name%3A%20%22Niladri%22%2C%20address%3A%20%22123%22%2C%20degree%3A%20%22GRAD%22%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2FSimilary%20%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20techobj3%20%3D%20new%20User(%7B%20name%3A%20%22Niladri%22%2C%20address%3A%20%22123%22%2C%20semester%3A%226th%22%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(techobj2.degree)%3B%20%2F%2FGRAD%0D%0Aconsole.log(techobj3.semester)%3B%20%2F%2F6th%0D%0A%0D%0A)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider creating a class User that contains all the fields that are same for the Teacher and the Student. Then you can create separate classes for Teacher and Student which will extend the class User, and contain the other fields that are unique for them, in this case degree for the teacher, and semester for the Student. **Maybe this will help:** [Extending Classes in Typescript](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/software-development/extending-classes-and-interfaces-using-typescript).